# Get progress of operation via ajax+ php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

I have a situation where my main task is to lookup domains names and respond about availability of a domain.Now the thing is this is a time consuming task..

Roughly the script taskes 25-30 seconds to complete..

I call the time consuming task via ajax..At the moment the script dumps entire data once it finishes..Now I need to show the progress of each record proecessed.

Bdw,I am parsing xml files in backend ..And I dont want to use DB for such a task..

I have tried following..

1.Used sessions to show progress(message about each record)..But when I make another call to get the progress through sessions the script becomes unresponsvie...Arent't the sessions being saved or accessed??

Comment: What have you done so far to check/debug session consistency? It's difficult to analyze what's going wrong without your code. So please provide something to work with instead of firing a hazy question and expecting us to come up with the solution from thin air ;)

Comment: One solution is that, you can use a progress bar where no need to show the progress status with it.

Comment: How exactly you are processing the sessions? creating unique session for each record & unsetting it?

Comment: Im just overwriting the session variables after processing each record..

Comment: I think only one script can read/write the session at a time, so the second request waits until the first one is done and has closed the session (and written the new values). You could create a progressfile somewhere that's only written to by the first request and only read by progress-requests.

Comment: I understand your concern about session_write_close()..You have suggested that I should use a logfile for this..Now it takes 0.12 s to process a record and after this processing i will write details to a logfile.The progress notifier ajax backend is called at 1/6th second.Concurrent writes and reads would be conflicting then??